# No login screen after logout

Tags: 11.10, login, lightdm

this is my first question about Ubuntu :)

Since this morning when I log out (top right icon, log out) I don't get the usual GUI login screen but I get this instead:

[image: http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/5637/photovu.jpg]

If I log in with the Ubuntu 2D option enabled everything works flawlessly.

Can somebody please suggest some step to take to understand what is going on? It looks like the X server gets stuck...

I can provide logs or whatever can be useful.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Gia

Comment: I get the same thing too but there is totally a blank (black) screen. I have to force the machine to reboot. This happened all of a sudden and I think the last batch of updates made it so. Is this related to LightDM? That was the update I noticed most recently that is likely related to this issue.

Comment: It seems that you might have a problem with your Graphic card. Which is your graphic card? Also you can try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1, login in the console there and type: sudo init 2. Then go back with Ctrl+Alt+F7 and you should see the login screen. This is only a workaround, there must be an issue in the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Like Christian said, it seems like you have a problem in the graphics configuration.

What graphics card are you using? Did you install proprietary drivers, or are you using the standard drivers? Did you update the drivers at all?

> To find the details of your driver, run `lshw -class video`, and look for the line with "configuration". The loaded driver is prefixed with "driver:".
>
> Sample output:
>
> ```
> ~$ > sudo lshw -class video
>    *-display
>        description: VGA compatible controller
>        product: GT216 [Quadro FX 880M]
>        vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
>        physical id: 0
>        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
>        version: a2
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>        configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
>        resources: irq:16 memory:cc000000-ccffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ce000000-cfffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:cd000000-cd07ffff
> ```
>
> In my case, since I am using the NVidia prop. drivers, I can check the driver version by running `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` which returns:
>
> > ```
> > ~# > dpkg -l | grep nvidia
> > ii  nvidia-common                          1:0.2.44                                Find obsolete NVIDIA drivers
> > ii  nvidia-current                         295.40-0ubuntu1                         NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library
> > ii  nvidia-settings                        295.33-0ubuntu1                         Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
> > ```

---

There could also be something wrong with the X Server configuration in the file `xorg.conf`. Open up that file in a text editor, and paste the contents here.

```
~$ > sudo -s                            /* enter root */
~# > find / -name 'xorg.conf'           /* find file, search in all directories */
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
~# > exit                               /* exit root */
exit
~$ > gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf           /* open file in editor */
```

Depending on how that file looks, you can reset the xorg.conf file using the terminal by doing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg` which will automatically generate an xorg.conf file while backing up the current one.

You can also delete the xorg.conf file. Then restart the X session with `startx`. Doing so will create a brand new xorg.conf file with the absence of not having one.

Hope that helps.