# login screen not displayed after logout

Tags: gnome, gdm, logout

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and I'm having the following problem. After booting my computer, gdm displays as expected and I can choose which account to log in to. However, if I then log out, I do not get the login screen any more, with instead just some text, similar to the problem described in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112609/no-login-screen-after-logout).

After logging out, I've found that Xorg is taking 100% CPU, and killing this process causes gdm to start up as usual again. One hacky solution I have found is to restart gdm after a session has finished by adding

```
killall -9 Xorg
```

to `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default`.

I'm using the nVidia proprietary driver on a laptop, with the laptop screen switched off and two external monitors (maybe a little unusual). A similar problem is described in [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#GDM_fails_on_logout), but this solution does not fix the problem.

So my question is, has anybody experienced this or something similar? What is the cause? And is there a better solution than just killing Xorg at the end of every session?

Comment: I've had this problem too, when I stopped using the proprietary driver the problem went away.  Thus the problem is surely the driver, or something in your xorg.conf as noted in the question you linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the NVIDIA 331 driver from [ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) solved this problem.

NVIDIA 304 driver also solved this problem but a Xorg crash report is appeared.

(Ubuntu GNOME 13.10, GNOME 3.8)

Comment: Please, provide a summary of things you link. That link to your google+ post will be broken sooner or later.

Comment: @olli Ok, I removed the link and added some more information from it into this post.